# what is the right verb for the overall process of "conducting" a thesis?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the right verb for the overall process of a thesis, including not only the writing process but also the research activities?

Analogous to "conducting research" I'd like to say "conducting a thesis"?

#### Edit:

Maybe this context is useful:

I want to thank a company for the possibility of doing my thesis together with them (meaning support, money, infrastrcture, laboratories, etc.). So, might I say:

> "I would like to thank `NAME_OF_CHIEF` for the possibility of **conducting the thesis** at `NAME_OF_COMPANY`"

Comment: "providing support"?

Comment: My first thought was that "conducting a thesis" didn't sound right. However, after you explained the context, the phrase sounded much more acceptable to me. I'd offer this suggested wording: _I would like to thank Robin Doe for the **opportunity** to conduct my thesis **research** at Acme Enterprises._ (As an aside, you might want to check out the sister site for [ell.SE].)

Comment: "... help in *producing* my thesis ..."?

Comment: The phrase “for the possibility of” is inappropriate; it hints that while support for thesis work was considered, it wasn't granted.

Comment: Or, "Thank you, Dr. Munchkin, for having given me the opportunity to research and complete this thesis within your excellent facilities at Ecolabs, Inc."  The phrases "I would like to thank" and "your ongoing support" are not necessary and unnecessarily wordy.  If you want to devote two sentences to your thank-you, you could add the following:  "I acknowledge and am truly grateful for your invaluable assistance and support."

Comment: If you have made your choice, as it seems from your final edit, then please accept the answer you preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, *writing a thesis* is generally understood, in context, to include the research work that the thesis is about.  I think it would suffice to say:

> I would like to thank Bill Lumbergh for the opportunity to write my thesis at Initech.

Comment: This is the most common way to refer to a finished thesis.

Answer (score 4):

You could describe the overall process of researching and writing a thesis as *[pursuing](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/pursue)* a thesis (as used [here](http://www.wjh.harvard.edu/psych/ug/thesis/step1/shouldyou.html)).

So you could write:

> I would like to thank Zaphod Beeblebrox for the opportunity to
>   pursue my thesis at Intergalactic Digital Research.

Comment: Looking at both links and analysing the verb, pursue, I'm not sure your suggestion is appropriate. Pursue basically means to follow, to continue something. You can pursue a hobby, a belief or studies. Here the OP has concluded his thesis, it has been written. Hmm...

Comment: @Mari-LouA _Pursue a thesis_ is common usage in this country, although I'll admit that you'll probably hear the more pedestrian _work on a thesis_ more often.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest 'working on' as the best answer

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an ancient question but I will add a link from Harvard University website for future viewers.

I think it answers some basic questions. There are 'writing a thesis', 'purusing a thesis' (as the title refers to), 'conducting research' and even 'doing a thesis' in the article(s) the link leads to.

Here is the link:

[Should you pursue the thesis?](http://undergrad.psychology.fas.harvard.edu/book/should-you-pursue-thesis)

Comment: I like *conducting **research*** as an answer to the question. The problem isn't the verb - it's the noun. The thesis is submitted material; the research is what one did in the process of producing the thesis.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if such a verb exists, from my experience the writing of a thesis or dissertation is separated from the research that goes into it. I would suggest "[constructing](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/construct)" or "[compiling](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/compile)".

As an alternative, you could consider something along the lines of thanking the company for their support in the completion of your degree.

Answer (score 0):

[**Cooperation**](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/cooperation) (UK: Co-operation)

I would like to thank [name of company] for their kind co-operation in writing/completing my thesis.

Answer (score 0):

**Prepare a thesis** also fits.

> Example : it is difficult to prepare a thesis without the help of any
>   mentor or guide

.

Answer (score -1):

"Carrying out" the thesis seems like a good fit for your purpose.

Comment: Why do you think this suitable? (I've never heard of someone "*carrying out* a thesis".) Can you give examples. You might find this help page useful: [How do I write a good answer?](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).